# How to render picklist values according to those available in the related object?

Tags: apex, lightning-experience, formula-field, picklist, dynamic-picklist

I am a newbie to salesforce and I am doing a project on hospital management system in it. I have Objects for Hospitals, Wards & Patients. Patient is in a lookup relationship with Ward and Hospital. In Ward I have a picklist called ward type(values: General, ICU, HCU, ICCU, Cabin). In Patient Object I also have a similar picklist called ward type but here I want to display only those wards which are available in the hospital where the patient is getting admitted(for e.g, ICCU and HCU are not present in every hospital so it is meaningless to show those options in ward type of such hospitals while filling a new patient detail).

Comment: In Patient if you keep a picklist on Hospiatal which contains the name of all the available hospitals then using field dependency your requirement can be attained. If you keep Hospital as controlling picklist and Ward as dependent picklist.

Comment: But it will help when I know which hospital has which ward, Hospital and its details will be entered by the respective employee and I need to render the options in real time

Comment: Other than salesforce I could query the database of Ward object filtered by hospital name entered and put the options in the drop-down list but I do not know how to put options in picklist in real-time fetching the records of wards, filtered by hospital name entered by the user in salesforce.

Comment: As per your requirement  I personally think that maybe configuration alone at least can't help you, you need to go for customization.

Comment: Can you tell me the approach of customization by which it could be done?(is it possible to render picklist values through apex?)